# Recurly python client raising UnicodeDecodeError when supplying non-ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, recurly

I'm trying to create accounts from the API of Recurly using the Python client.
Python 2.7, recurly 2.2.17

When creating a new account with a first name (or any other attribute actually) containing non-ascii characters (fetched as a `unicode`), saving the entity raises `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte [...]`

A simple `account.first_name = u'Frédérique-Fançois'.encode('utf-8')` still raises the same error but at another level in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recurly.API_KEY` and `recurly.SUBDOMAIN` must be passed `str` objects.

You might be in trouble if your are using [`unicode_literals`](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html) or if your configuration source provides `unicode` values. In this case, you need to convert them either through `str` if values do not contain non-ascii characters, or with `encode()`.

E.g.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# You can force it like this
account.API_KEY = str('my api key here')
account.SUBDOMAIN = str('advanseez')
```

Doing this ensures that the underlying `httplib` will not convert HTTP headers to `unicode` thus conflicting with any non-ascii characters present the message body which is always `str` when working with Recurly client.

This way you can safely assign attributes in any Recurly resource using `unicode`.

E.g.

```
account = recurly.Account(account_code='12345689', first_name=u'Frédérique-François')
account.save()  # Works without raising UnicodeDecodeError
```

For detailed demonstration of the problem, workaround and explanation of the problem's origin see (Note use of `import unicode_literals`, which changes default string type as Unicode): https://gist.github.com/maximehardy/d3a0a6427d2b6791b3dc

Comment: Please include the external description inline of the answer.

Comment: Looking at the referenced description, it seems to be caused because you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. The problem would only arise in the rare case that the user passed a Unicode object as the `API_KEY` or `SUBDOMAIN`.

Comment: Yes that's it, however it is a good practice to work with `unicode` rather than `str`. Or simpler use Python 3 which solved the problems around unicode support.

Comment: This answer is really confusing to regular users of Python 2.x. They'll wonder why they have to make an `str` from an `str` to pass as `API_KEY` and `SUBDOMAIN`.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thanks for your advices that I took into consideration to improve the answer